# TIKA server returned status 500. I have latest version of TIKA installed from pip and JAVA 8. I have to extract text from my PDF

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache-tika

**Here is the code I executed.**

```
from tika import parser

file = 'sample.pdf'

file_data = parser.from_file(file)

text = file_data['content']

print(text)
```

**I am getting error -**

> [WARNI]  Tika server returned status: 500
>
> None

Comment: What's the log message for the error?

Comment: I'm also observing such messages. What does it mean?

[MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Tika server returned status: 500

Tika runs in server mode as follows:

java -Xmx2048m -jar tika-server.jar --host=hostname.domain.com

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same error and for me restarting the Tika sever worked.

Running this should yield the PID

`ps aux | grep java | grep tika`

and then kill the tika server and restart your python app.

Answer (score 0):

This error 500 seems to be returned when Tika Server fails for reasons such as running out of memory in heap, and other exceptions I yet have to figure out. I see those exceptions in the Tika Server log.
As a workaround, in my client using python-tika, I'll start to retry the query (parser.from_file()) a few times when it returns null content. This is just a workaround.

But in order to avoid the 500 error, we need to find out what makes the Tika Server fail (or crash?).

The warning message comes from `tika.py.callServer()`